# Improve performance of 7-sided die roll simulation from a 6-sided die implementation

Tags: c, performance, algorithm, random

In a different [StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/901222), the following algorithm (based on arithmetic coding) was presented as an efficient method for generating outcomes of a 7-sided die, when all that is given is a 6-sided die:

```
int rand7()
{
  static double a=0, width=7;  // persistent state

  while ((int)(a+width) != (int)a)
  {
    width /= 6;
    a += (rand6()-1)*width;
  }

  int n = (int)a;
  a -= n; 
  a *= 7; width *= 7;
  return (n+1);
}
```

Not being a true mathematician, I'll do the best I can to explain how this algorithm works:

At the start of each call to `rand7()`, `width` is the ratio 7<sup>s</sup>/6<sup>t</sup>, and `a` is a non-negative value with the property that `a + width` lies in the interval [0, 7) after the base case. When entering the `while` loop, `width` is the maximal value that can be added to `a`. If `floor(a + width)` is different from `floor(a)`, then a random choice of { 0, `width`*1/6, `width`*1/3, `width`*1/2, `width`*2/3, `width`*5/6 } is added to `a`, and the exponent `t` is incremented by one (reducing the value of `width` by a power of 6). Note that after an iteration, the property that `a + width` lies in the interval [0, 7) remains invariant. When `width` becomes smaller than the difference of `ceil(a) - a`, the iterations stop. The loop adds more entropy into `a` so long as doing so can actually affect the outcome of the die roll, and intuitively, *this is building a random real number in the range of [0, 7) using base 6*. After leaving the loop, the die roll is taken to be `floor(a) + 1`, and `a` is reduced to its fractional part. At that point `a + width` lies in the interval [0, 1). To prepare for the next call and to maintain the invariant property, both `a` and `width` are scaled up by a factor of 7 (for `width`, this increases the exponent `s` by 1).

The above explains the workings of the inductive step. Analysis of the base case is left as an exercise for the interested reader.

Of course, from an efficiency standpoint, the use of floating-point arithmetic immediately pops out as a performance drag (assuming the performance of `rand6()` is already sufficient and itself cannot be improved). While maintaining this arithmetic coding algorithm, what is the best approach to removing the use of floating-point?

Comment: The call to `rand()` itself is probably the biggest time-consumer.

Comment: @Mysticial: You mean the call to `rand6()`? Its performance was not specified. Let's assume its performance is already at an acceptable level, and the goal is to let `rand7()` approach `rand6()`'s performance as closely as possible.

Comment: Floating point is probably not a problem for performance, but it's a big problem for correctness. It will bias the results.

Comment: @R..: I do not see how using `double` will significantly bias the result. Could you explain? As to performance, if this algorithm can be ported to integer only computations in a straight-forward manner, I am hoping it will run faster on processors that lack a FPU.

Comment: @jxh `double` has enough bits that it probably will not *significantly* bias the results. But it will bias them. Whoever uses this will have decide if it biases the results too much for their use or not. Or let me put that another way, whether the bias is significant or not, depends on the use case.

Comment: On a system with software floats, especially IEEE floats implemented in software, specialized integer version will be much faster, that's for sure.

Comment: @hyde: it's trivial to convert to fixed point, particularly as the range of the two double variables is extremely limited. Since neither can be negative or greater than 7, the simplest fixed point representation would be unsigned 4.60 (3.61 might work, too, but I have some doubts about overflow). With fixed point, addition is just integer addition and multiplication or division by an integer is just multiplication or division by the same integer. `cast to int` is `x>>60`, and `x-floor(x)` is `x&((1UL<<60)-1UL)`. So essentially no overhead. And that gives you a few extra bits to play with.

Comment: Fixed point does not solve the bias. You want an exact result not a better or worse approximation.

Comment: @R..: agreed. It was simply a comment about the computation.

Comment: @rici Mmm, true, though better be careful that rounding won't be different, introducing different bias. And about bias, this question is indeed about computation using the given algorithm, as far as I can see.

Comment: @hyde: It's possible that using `width /= 6;` instead of the possibly more correct `width += 3; width /= 6;` introduces some bias, but it's a bias in the 60th bit or so, which I don't think compares with round-off error in the 53rd bit, as with doubles. I didn't see any visible bias with either the double or fixed-point versions, but I didn't do anything more sophisticated than a histogram and a pixel-map, and I have no doubt that there is a bias. Philosophically, a bias of 2^-50 is annoying. In practice, however, it's very hard to detect.

Comment: @hyde: I understand now. Bias is introduced because 1/6 cannot be expressed exactly with floating point, the algorithm does not take special measures to correct it. This will cause the algorithm to tend to favor whichever of the intervals [0,1/6), [1/6,1/3), [1/3,1/2), [1/2,2/3), [2/3,5/6), [5/6,1) is actually wider because the allotment of bits isn't even. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following up on a comment I made, here's the fixed point version of the algorithm. It uses unsigned 4.60 (that is, there are 60 bits in the fractional part of the number), which is a few more bits than you can get out of a `double`:

```
int rand7fixed() {
    static uint64_t a = 0;
    static uint64_t width = 7UL<<60;
    static const uint64_t intmask = 0xfUL<<60;

    while (((a+width)&intmask) != (a&intmask)) {
      width /= 6;
      a += (rand6()-1)*width;
    }

    int n = a >> 60;
    a &=~intmask;
    a *= 7;
    width *= 7;
    return n+1;
}
```

The above turns out to be about a third faster than the double version in the OP (see benchmark results and notes below). I suspect that the time-waster is not the floating point arithmetic, but rather the conversions from `double` to `int`.

As R.. points out, this does not fix the bias; it merely reduces it. A simple and reasonably fast unbiased algorithm would be to repeatedly generate two `rand6()` values `h` and `l` until at least one of them is non-zero, and then return `h*6+l % 7`:

```
int rand7_2() {
  int hi, lo;
  do {
    hi = rand6() - 1;
    lo = rand6() - 1;
  } while (hi + lo);
  return (hi * 6 + lo) % 7 + 1;
}
```

If you feel the need to reduce the number of calls to `rand6`, you can use the fact that 6<sup>12</sup> is only slightly more than 7<sup>11</sup> to generate 11 7-die rolls at a time. It is still necessary to discard some of the sets of 12 6-rolls in order to remove bias; the frequency of discarding sets will be `(612−711)/612)`, or approximately 1 in 11, so on average you'll need about 1.19 6-rolls per 7-roll. You could do better by using 25 6-rolls to generate 23 7-rolls (1.13 6-rolls per 7-roll) but that doesn't quite fit into 64-bit arithmetic, so the marginal advantage in calls to `rand6` would be chewed up by doing the calculations in 128-bit.

Here's the 11/12 solution:

```
int rand7_12() {
    static int avail = 0;
    static uint32_t state = 0;
    static const uint32_t discard = 7*7*7*7*7*7*7*7*7*7*7; // 7 ** 11
    static const int out_per_round = 11;
    static const int in_per_round = 12;

    if (!avail) {
      do {
        state = rand6() - 1;
        for (int needed = in_per_round - 1; needed; --needed)
          state = state * 6 + rand6() - 1;
      }
      while (state >= discard);
      avail = out_per_round;
    }
    int rv = state % 7;
    state /= 7;
    --avail;
    return rv + 1;
}
```

In theory you should be able to reduce the ratio to `log76`, which is about 1.086. For example, you could do that by generating 895 7-rolls from 972 6-rolls, discarding about one in 1600 of the sets for an average of 1.087 6-rolls/7-roll, but you'd need 2513-bit arithmetic to hold the state.

I tested all four functions with a not-very-precise benchmark which calls rand7 700,000,000 times and then prints a histogram of the results. The results:

```
                                                  User time with
Algorithm       User time      rand6() calls     cycling rand6()
----------      ---------      -------------     ---------------
double          32.6 secs          760223193           13.2 secs
fixed           29.4 secs          760223194            7.9 secs
2 for 1         40.2 secs         1440004276
12 for 11       23.7 secs          840670008
```

The underlying rand6() implementation above is the Gnu standard c++ library's `uniform_int_distribution<>(1,6)` using `mt19937_64` (a 64-bit Mersenne Twister) as a PRNG. To try to get a better handle on the amount of time spent in the standard library, I also ran the test using a simple cyclic counter as a pseudorandom number generator; the remaining 13.2 and 7.9 seconds represent (roughly) the time spent in the algorithm itself, from which we can say that the fixed-point algorithm is about 40% faster. (It's hard to get  good reading on the combining algorithms because the fixed sequence makes branch prediction much easier and reduces the number of rand6 calls, but both took less than 5 seconds.)

Finally, the histograms in case anyone wants to check for bias (also includes a run with `std::uniform_int_distribution(1,7)` for reference):

```
Algorithm          1          2          3          4          5          6          7
---------  ---------  ---------  ---------  ---------  ---------  ---------  ---------
reference  100007522  100002456  100015800  100005923   99972185  100008908   99987206
double     100014597  100005975   99982219   99986299  100004561  100011049   99995300
fixed      100009603  100009639  100034790   99989935   99995502   99981886   99978645
2 for 1    100004476   99997766   99999521  100001382   99992802  100003868  100000185
12 for 11   99988156  100004974  100020070  100001912   99997472   99995015   99992401
```

Comment: Also, my hunch is that `rand7fixed()` will outperform `rand7b()`.

Comment: @jxh: perhaps, but it depends on how fast `rand6()` is. For modern hardware, I recommend benchmarking. Hunches are often wrong; at least, mine are. (My hunch was that `rand7fixed` would be about the same speed as your `rand7`, but no.)

Comment: I was certain an integer arithmetic version would outperform the floating point version (on x86). However, I genuinely thought the algorithm used floating truncation as a means to defeat bias. Your performance measure would be even more significant if you factored out the cost of calling `rand6()` itself.

Comment: Also, note that for `rand7b()`, `rand6()` returns numbers in the range { 1..6 }, so the assignment to `hi` and `lo` should also each be decremented by 1.

Comment: @jxh: `(6 * (hi - 1) + (lo - 1)) % 7 == (6 * hi + lo - 7) % 7 == (6 * hi + lo) % 7`. But I should have put a comment. :)

Comment: @jxh, also my benchmark had a bug, although fixed is still faster. Will edit in a minute.

Comment: Ah, the issue is the `while` condition.

Comment: @jxh: Right. In the actual code, the condition was "hi + lo == 2" but I changed it to the decrement form for presentation. Answer now has benchmark results.

Answer (score 4):

[Edit]

Need to to improve the far below method, but follows is a simple *unbiased* method. It is inefficient as it calls `rand6()` at least twice ever time.  (Assume `rand6()` is unbiased)

```
int rand7simple(void) {
  int product;
  do {
    int a = rand6() - 1;
    int b = rand6() - 1;
    product = a*6 + b;  // produce unbiased distributed numbers 0 .. 35
  } while (product >= 35);  // Redo 1 in 36 times
  // produce unbiased distributed numbers 0 .. 34
  return product%7 + 1;
}
```

---

For every 6 calls to `rand7()`, `rand6()` should be called 7 times.
Initialize a wide integer state to minimize bias.

Need to test this later. GTG.

```
int rand7(void) {
  static int count = -1;
  static unsigned long long state = 0;
  if (count < 0) {
    count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<25; i++) {
      state *= 6;
      state += rand6();
    }
  int retval = state % 7;
  state /= 7;

  int i = (count >= 6) + 1; 
  if (++count > 6) count = 0;
  while (i-- > 0) {
    state *= 6;
    state += rand6();
  }
  return retval;
}
```

Comment: Note that 7^6=117649 but 6^7=279936. IOW 6 rolls of 7-sided dice have less possible values than 7 rolls of 6-sided dice. Does your code account for that?

Comment: @hyde Was thinking about that.  The call rate to `rand6()` might maybe could be adjusted.  At first blush, it looks like 7 out of 6 time is a bit too often.  Calling too often is not a problem, just an inefficiency.  I'll ponder this more, but I hope the general idea is clear.  Pull out numbers with `retval = state % 7; state /= 7;` and replentish with 1 or 2 calls to `state *= 6; state += rand6();`  Now I gotta go!

Comment: When you have time, I hope you do fix the answer or at least add a warning to the answer text. Intuitively, I'd think `state` will overflow and wrap, because 6-sided dices increase it more than 7-sided dices decrease it. Incidentally, this is why the question code uses `double`, much simpler to deal with this than with integers.

Comment: I too had written the 6^12 and 7^11 code to get unbiased output, but had not completed validation before [@rici fine answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25376065/2410359) was accepted - so will not add it.  The lesson I took away from this post was that unbiased random number generation is subtly challenging to code & prove and typically takes a fair amount of time to insure gremlins don't exist.